# Hibernate decimal(20,3) mapping failing

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I want to create a decimal column with precision 20 and scale 3 in a table,
What i did is:

1. create following variable in pojo class

   ```
   private BigDecimal  minimumValue;
   ```
2. In .hbm file i am setting property value as

   ```
   <property name="minimumValue" type="DECIMAL" precision="20" scale="3"/>
   ```

I am getting following error:

org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: DECIMAL, at table: TEST_DECIMAL, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(minimumValue)]

Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, Got it solved. i changed <property name="minimumValue" type="DECIMAL" precision="20" scale="3"/> to <property name="minimumValue" precision="20" scale="3"/> and it worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove type="DECIMAL".
The type attribute holds the hibernate mapping type, this mapping types will convert from Java to SQL data type.
In your case you can use type="big_decimal".